# Transfer/copy material slot assignements to identical mesh

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a geometry with many materials assigned on different faces of the model.
Then I have the exact same geometry without any material.

How can I copy/transfer all these materials and their assignements into this identical geometry?

Comment: cannot you just duplicate the object with all the materials? Why do you need this if they are identical?

Comment: Well it could be various of reason why you can not just copy. Let's say you had to adjust the model outside (zbrush, 3dcoat... choose you favourite app) and the model is back - and you want your material setup back! If the topology is the same, it should be possible, but how?

Comment: I dont think there is a native way to transfer material "assignments". You would have to look for python ... just for curiosity - if you enable Viewport Overlay > Developer > [Indices](https://imgur.com/e14NS4Q), can you confirm they match on both objects?

Comment: I confirmed - thank you. The problme was solved - shape keys helped :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This A is not answering your Q, but can be a solution :) From your description I understood you export a mesh out of blender, you change vertices position and import your model back to Blender - topology is kept. So you can try ...*

---

Instead of tranfering material assignments, you can transfer a shape of imported mesh to original one (with materials assigned).

Select imported than original object and search for **Join as Shape** operator.

[image]

This will generates two shape-keys - original (Basis) and another shape-key named by imported object (*Properties > Data Properties > Shape Keys*). Select the second one and change *Value* to 1.

[image]

Note: This technique will work only for two objects with the same vertex numbering ... check *Viewport Overlay > Developer > Indices*

[image]

Comment: Thank you - that's a nice workaround and basically it works - I haven't thought about that :)

Comment: Great :) ... possibly small benefit - with each edit out of blender it can be added as another shapekey - so it can works like a versioning, easily to swap or combine :)